# Node JS Async Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I wrote my 1st application in Node.js with MongoDB and I came across the situation where I need to have 2 `db.collection.update` statements depending on an IF/ELSE condition.
I am trying to return back the operation details in a `resJSON` JS object but seems like callback is executing before the `db.collection.update` statements are completed and the default value of `resJSON` is getting back in response each time.

detail code:

```
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var passwordGen = require('../../lib/passwordGen');

var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', request);
server.listen(8080,'127.0.0.1');
function request(request, response) {
    var userData = '';

    request.on('data', function(data) 
    {
        userData += data;
    });
    request.on('end', function() 
    {
      async.auto({                           
        allProcess: function(callback){                                 
            var resJSON  = {'inserted':0,'disabled':0,'error':''};        
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(userData);   
           if(jsonData.length > 0){

            var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

            MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test_db", function(err,db){
                  if(err) { return console.dir(err); }

                   var collection = db.collection('users');
                   var arrDisableRec = [];  

                   for(i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
                      var action = jsonData[i]['action'].toLowerCase();

                      if(action == 'disable'){           
                          arrDisableRec.push(jsonData[i]['email']);                                            
                      }else{
                          var date = new Date();
                          var obj = { 
                                      'createdISO':date,
                                      'created':date,
                                      'updated':date,
                                      'updatedISO':date,
                                      'email':jsonData[i]['email'],
                                      'firstName':jsonData[i]['firstname'],
                                      'lastName':jsonData[i]['lastname'],
                                      'password':passwordGen.getPassword(),
                                      'enabled':true,
                                      'active':true,
                                      'downloaded':true,
                                      'defaultServings':2,
                                      'name':''
                                    };
                                 collection.update(
                                     {'email':jsonData[i]['email']},
                                     {$setOnInsert:obj},
                                     {upsert: true},  
                                     function(err,numberAffected,rawResponse) { 
                                        if(typeof numberAffected.result.upserted != 'undefined'){
                                          resJSON['inserted'] = resJSON['inserted'] + numberAffected.result.upserted.length; 
                                        }   

                                        if(typeof numberAffected.result.nModified != 'undefined'){                                                                    
                                          resJSON['disabled'] = resJSON['disabled'] + parseInt(numberAffected.result.nModified);
                                        }                                                 
                                        if(typeof numberAffected.result.writeError != 'undefined'){                   
                                          resJSON['error'] ='Error Code:'+(numberAffected.result.writeError.code)+', '+numberAffected.result.writeError.errmsg;                                                                                
                                        }
                                        console.log(resJSON); //shows correct values           
                                    }
                          );
                      }     
                      if(arrDisableRec.length > 0){
                          collection.update(
                                     {'email':{$in:arrDisableRec}},
                                     {$set:{'enabled':false}},
                                     {multi:true},
                                     function(err,numberAffected,rawResponse) {  
                                      if(typeof numberAffected.result.upserted != 'undefined'){
                                        resJSON['inserted'] = resJSON['inserted'] + numberAffected.result.upserted.length; 
                                      }   

                                      if(typeof numberAffected.result.nModified != 'undefined'){                                                                    
                                        resJSON['disabled'] = resJSON['disabled'] + parseInt(numberAffected.result.nModified);
                                      }                                                 
                                      if(typeof numberAffected.result.writeError != 'undefined'){                   
                                        resJSON['error'] ='Error Code:'+(numberAffected.result.writeError.code)+', '+numberAffected.result.writeError.errmsg;                                                                                
                                      }     

                                        console.log(resJSON);   //shows correct values    
                                    }
                             );
                        }
                   }          

               });
            } 
            callback(resJSON);
        }         
        },function(resJSON){
            response.writeHead(200,{
                  'Content-Type': 'text/json'
                });                          
            response.end(JSON.stringify(resJSON));    //replies back with default resJSON only.         
        });        
    }); 
 }
```

Any suggestions/directions please?

Thanks

Comment: well you are doing it all wrong. You are putting a asynchronous task inside a for loop which will complete all its iteration before you get returned from your update actions for all items.
I recommend you async,js library. Learn and Use the async.each function. It should fix your callback getting called first issue.

Comment: Per StackOverflow guidelines, code relevant to the question should be pasted into the question, not only available in an external link.

Comment: @jfriend00 it was too long to paste here

Comment: @SumanLama you mean it is not possible to gather the info this way?I will have to re adjust the code?

Comment: Questions about code MUST include the relevant code in your question.  The code you linked to can be distilled down to the relevant parts and pasted here.  Those are the StackOverflow guidelines.  Links have a habit of becoming dysfunctional or changed over time and then this question becomes meaningless as a repository of knowledge which is an important part of StackOverflow's value.

Comment: it is possible but you would have to use promises. The thing is you have called your callback at the end. But node won't call after every thing above is completed, rather it will start all the update action, wont wait for the response and then call your callback. You will have to call your callback after all your update actions are completed. `The best option would be to use asyncjs library. If you do not want to use it there are some short hacks by creating a counter.`

Comment: @jfriend00 Im sorry. Its done now.

Comment: @SumanLama there is not a way to call the callback after the updates are completed? 
I tried to use async.auto on someones advice but seems like this is incorrect way to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the callback at then end of the callback chain.

For example

```
console.log(resJSON); //shows correct values
callback(null, resJSON);
```

you will have to make sure that every callback chain end point calls the callback. To handle the for loop you will have to have a mechanism to join all the end points of all the async calls done inside the for loop.

for example

```
if(err) {
   return callback(err);
}
```

notice that I used the `function callback(err, res)` standard node prototype instead of your `function callback(res)`

better yet, use an async flow library like `async` or a promise library like `bluebird`

Comment: I need to have a callback chain inside the update statement?. Im sorry..im somewhat confused here..can you please help out with an example if possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is a counter solution for your issue. It should solve your case for now. Try reading async library.  It will be very useful for later.

```
    var counter = 0;
    function commoncallback(err,numberAffected,rawResponse) { 
        if(typeof numberAffected.result.upserted != 'undefined'){
            resJSON['inserted'] = resJSON['inserted'] + numberAffected.result.upserted.length; 
        }
        if(typeof numberAffected.result.nModified != 'undefined'){                                                                    
            resJSON['disabled'] = resJSON['disabled'] + parseInt(numberAffected.result.nModified);
        }                                                 
        if(typeof numberAffected.result.writeError != 'undefined'){                   
            resJSON['error'] ='Error Code:'+(numberAffected.result.writeError.code)+', '+numberAffected.result.writeError.errmsg;                                                                                
        }
        console.log(resJSON); //shows correct values   
        counter --;
        if(counter == 0) callback(resJSON); //call your main call back here
    }
    for (i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++) {
        if(firstCase) {
            counter ++;
            collection.update({'email':{$in:arrDisableRec}},
                              {$set:{'enabled':false}},
                              {multi:true},commoncallback);
        } else {
              //another update action
              counter++;
        }
    }
```